# Reference Error when Importing TypeScript Module into JS File

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, pug, commonjs

I am currently facing an issue while introducing TypeScript into a portion of my project. My project uses CommonJS for module management and Pug as a template engine. I'm attempting to import a class from a TypeScript file into a JavaScript file, but I'm encountering a syntax error.

**Problem:**

When I import a class from a TypeScript file into a JavaScript file using the import syntax, I'm getting the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './Grid.js' does not provide an export named 'Grid'`

**Context:**

The project utilizes CommonJS for module management.
I have integrated TypeScript into a section of the code. The TypeScript files are transpiled into JavaScript ES5.
The problem arises when importing a TypeScript class into a JavaScript file. (btw i'm pretty sure I can't convert this JS file to TS because TS doesn't let me deal with a variable sent from my pug file, so that's why i want to do it this way).
I have not yet implemented a bundler like Webpack.

**Code:**

Here's how I'm importing the "Grid" class into a JavaScript file :

```js
import { Grid } from "./Grid.js";
```

And here's the content of the "Grid.ts" file (TypeScript):

```js
export class Grid {
  // ...
}
```

Finally, here is my tsconfig.json file :

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "types": ["node", "jest"],
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

**Actions Taken:**

1. The TypeScript files are successfully transpiled into JavaScript ES5 and are stored in the "dist" folder after compilation.
2. I've verified that the import paths match the actual file paths.
3. I tried various ways of importing the TS file, but maybe i just missed a correct one

**Question:**

I'm stuck and unable to resolve this error. How can I correctly import TypeScript classes into a JavaScript file ? I'm open to using a bundler but I don't know at all how to setup it though. Are there any specific considerations I should be aware of when dealing with Pug and CommonJS?

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Best regards

Comment: Avoid named exports if you're targeting common JS and using ES module syntax

Comment: How so ? What should i use instead ?

Comment: First, to ensure clarity specify `"module": CommonJS"` in tsconfig.json which determines how module syntax is transformed in both TS and JS files. Then either use `export = ..` and `import.. = require..` in your TypeScript files and `module.exports = ..` and `const.. = require..` in your JS files _**or**_` set `"esModuleInterop": true` in tsconfig.json. in the latter case, you can continue to the esm module throughout your project and TSC will transform it properly in both TS and JS sources. Do not mix esm and CJS module constructs in any of the source files however. Consistency will help here

Comment: Here's a highly related question and answer which I hope you find helpful https://stackoverflow.com/q/49640121/1915893