# How to use Javascript File in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, typescript

I am currently developing in Next.js and React (TypeScript).

Then a problem arose.

It is the inability to load js files.

**I have tried the following.** 
　・Import javascript modules 
　　`import * as module from '../../../script';` 
　・require code
　　`const remise = require('../../../script/rtoken-3.0.0');` 　　
Neither did it work.

Please tell me how to write it.
Thank You.

Here is the code.
・js(path:../../../script/rtoken-3.0.0.min.js)

```
(function (window, undefined) {
  var CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 5000;

  function rtoken() {
    this.consumerID = '';
    this.SessionTimeout = 60000;
    this.ConnectionAddress = '';
    ～
    var rtoken = this;
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
      rtoken.Abort();
    };
    window.onpagehide = function () {
      rtoken.Abort();
    };
  }
  rtoken.prototype = {
    Init: function () {
      this.consumerID = getUUID();
      this.SessionTimeout = 60000;
      this.TokenType = '';
　　　～
    },
    Create: function () {
      var self = this;
      requestData = "{\"SessionID\":\"" + this.consumerID + "\"," + "\"TokenType\":\"" + this.TokenType + "\"," + "\"Sequence\":\"" + this.Sequence + "\"," + "\"Options\":\"" + this.Options + "\"}";
      exJsonp(self.ConnectionAddress, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, requestData, "CreateToken", function (data) {
      　～
      });
    },
  };

  function exJsonp(url, htttimeout, RequestData, MethodName, Callback) {
    try {
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: encodeURIComponent(RequestData),
        jsonpCallback: MethodName,
        timeout: htttimeout,
        success: function (data) {
          Callback(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
          Callback(data);
        },
        complete: function (data) {}
      });
    } catch (e) {
      Callback(null);
    }
  };

  function getUUID() {
    var uuid, i, random;
    uuid = "";
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
      ～
    }
    return uuid;
  };
  if (!window.remise) {
    window.remise = {};
  }
  window.remise.rtoken = rtoken;
})(window);
```

tsfile()

```
～
import * as rtoken from '../../../script/rtoken-3.0.0.min';　// ×

export const Index = (props) => {
  const jsModule = require('../../../script/rtoken-3.0.0');
　var token= jsModule();
  // What does not come in to token
  console.log('token:', token);

  return (
    null
  )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mixing JavaScript and TypeScript in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49640121/mixing-javascript-and-typescript-in-node-js)

Comment: @StavNoy Thank you. But no resolution was reached....

Comment: Now that I look again, I see `rtoken` isn't an ES module, but the older "global" module. ("UMD", I think). Best is to check the docs on this `rtoken` library. If not, `allowUmdGlobalAccess` might be helpful: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-5/#the---allowumdglobalaccess-flag

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you allow turn on `allowJs` option in `tsconfig.json`. And after you import depending on your configuration, you can ignore the linting errors

Comment: yes. I already have allowjs in tsconfig.json...

Comment: so no errors but token is undefined?

Comment: It seems that jQuery and React are not compatible.

Comment: you can use them both together. but it is not practical as React interacts with VDOM and JQuery interacts with actual DOM. so you would see red flags everywhere unless you find a good way to control them